# Realmで複数のデータベースを生成するには？

Tags: realm

Realmで複数のデータベースを生成したいと思っています。

例えば
default.realm
second.realm
を作りたいと思っていて、
最初にRealmを初期化した時に、一緒にすべてのObjectがdefault.realmのスキーマとして作られてしまいます。

これをsecond.realmにするものと分けるにはどのようにすればよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

現在はファイルごとに使われるスキーマを選択することはできません。

そのような要望に対応する機能は検討中で、下記のIssueで議論されており、いまのところ、`RLMConfiguration`という一括でRealmの設定を行うための機能の一部として実装される予定です。

https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1506
https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1584

現在は定義したスキーマは複数のファイルで共通に使われる仕様となります。
使わないテーブルが存在するのは気になるかもしれませんが、仕組み上、性能その他に影響は全くありませんので（Realmはスキーマの情報をファイル内に持たない）、現状は気にせずに使っていただくのが良いと思います。

Answer (score 2):

cocoa/swift 版は把握できてないですが、 Java 版にはRealmConfiguration の一機能として導入済みでした。

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#schemas

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C, Swfitでもバージョン0.95から、Configurationオブジェクトを使って、スキーマごとにモデル定義を使い分けることができるようになりました。

https://realm.io/jp/docs/objc/latest/#section-29